# How to retrieve from SharePoint file details using Power Shell?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2013, metadata

I am trying to delete documents which are modified before 15 days using `powershell`. Now I am able to delete the document by using the below `powershell` code. Now the requirement is before deleting the document, I need to send the file name with the modified date to a log file.So how can I retrieve the filename and modified date before deleting each document. My code is as below:

```
$DeleteBeforeDate = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility]::CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime([DateTime]::Now.AddDays(-15))
           $caml= '<Where> <Lt> <FieldRef Name="Modified" /><Value Type="DateTime">{0}</Value> </Lt> </Where>' -f $DeleteBeforeDate 
           $query=new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
           $query.Query=$caml
            if($list.Items.Count -gt 0)
             {
           $collListItems=$list.GetItems($query)
             }
           $count = $collListItems.Count - 1

      for($intIndex = $count; $intIndex -gt -1; $intIndex--) 
        { 
        "Deleting record: " + $intIndex 
        #Write-Host  $collListItems.($intIndex)("ID");

        $collListItems.Delete($intIndex); 
        }
```

Thanks in advance!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to obtain the metadata through the SPListItem:

```
$collListItems[$intIndex]["FileRef"]
$collListItems[$intIndex]["Modified"]
```

Or with an extra step:

```
$listitem = $collListItems[$intIndex]
$title = $listitem["Title"]
$modified = $listitem["Modified"]
```

The column-name between [] is just the static name of the fields

More info: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20831.sharepoint-a-complete-guide-to-getting-and-setting-fields-using-powershell.aspx#Displaying_all_the_fields